# Maximum possible for corner radius of a view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, material-components-android, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Is there a standard way to set the corner radius of CardView and TextView to the maximum possible value in `ConstraintLayout`?

Suppose I have two horizontal guidelines `H10` (`10%`) and `H24` (`24%`) and I've created a TextView/CardView  from `H10` to `H24`. Now how can one make corners radius of this TextView/CardView  to maximum radius possible? (here the max value is `(24-10)/2 = 7%`)

Once I've set the corner radius of a button of **defined height** `48dp` to `30dp` (instead of rational value `24dp`) and it became very ugly. So I thought if there is a way to set corner radius automatically to maximum possible value? (in xml not in code)

I've tried to do this by setting background of the view with an appropriate shape but I think it is same as setting corner radius to TextView/CardView  directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

    <corners 
        android:radius="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

I usually use the following for TextViews with `wrap_content` as its height: (I don't want to use `wrap_content` because I want to use `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` property`)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

style="@style/myTextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingVertical="0dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

where

```
<style name="myTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">24dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">24dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">24dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">24dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="hintAnimationEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about all views but the following works like a charm for material components: just set `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.Full"`

Examle:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.Full"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"/>
```

[image]